# start week day from sunday - javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to retrieve a date by providing day number of a specific week

E.g

When I say

```
day: 1
```

It should provide me:

```
2023-01-15
```

What I have tried so far is:

```js
function calculatedDate (day){

    let date = new Date();
    let dayAtDate = date.getDay();
    let dayDiff = day - dayAtDate;
    
    if(dayDiff < 0){
        dayDiff = 7 + dayDiff;
    }

    let desiredDate = date.setDate(date.getDate() + dayDiff);

    return new Date(desiredDate);
}

console.log(calculatedDate(1));
```

Now the problem with above code is that it considers `day: 1` as monday, but I want `day: 1` to be sunday here.

Can anyone help me with the best possible way here?

Answer (score 0):

Sunday is 0, Monday is 1 here :

```js
function calculatedDate (day) {
    let date = new Date();
    let dayAtDate = date.getDay();
    let dayDiff = day - (dayAtDate + 1); // change here
    if (dayDiff < 0) {
        dayDiff = 7 + dayDiff;
    }
    let desiredDate = date.setDate(date.getDate() + dayDiff);
    return new Date(desiredDate);
}
console.log(calculatedDate(1));
```

Comment: I want to supply 1 as Sunday not 0

Comment: You want the week to start on Sunday, right ?

Comment: Yes but if I provide 1 it should consider Sunday, I am strictly bound to start day from 1 instead of 0

Comment: I think you need to reword your question. You have provided an example input and expected output that all answers address accordingly, where the input is 1 and the output is the date of the upcoming Sunday.

Comment: I think my question makes clear sense, if I provide day: 2 it should return upcoming Monday date

Comment: As I said, the solutions provided seemingly do as you ask; there is evidently some miscommunication. Can you elaborate on what exactly is wrong with the solutions provided?

Answer (score 0):

How about just -1 the provided day? that should solve it:

```js
function calculatedDate (day){

    let date = new Date();
    let dayAtDate = date.getDay();
    day = day - 1;
    let dayDiff = day - dayAtDate;
    
    if(dayDiff < 0){
        dayDiff = 7 + dayDiff;
    }

    let desiredDate = date.setDate(date.getDate() + dayDiff);

    return new Date(desiredDate);
}

console.log(calculatedDate(1));
```

You'd probably want to add some validation on the input parameter `day`, make sure it's a number and 1 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

The current day will be 0, account for this by making the following change.

```
if(dayDiff < 0){
    dayDiff = 6 + dayDiff;
}
```